# Controller for Buttons Sencha Touch 2

Tags: sencha-touch

I have this problem that I can ref a button for control it. I don't understand the logic of Controllers, see my example code:

```
Ext.define('myMoney.controller.Inicio', {
    extend: 'Ext.app.Controller',

    config: {
        refs: {
            loginForm: '#loginForm',
            logButton: '#logButton',
        },
        control: {
            logButton: {
                tab: "autenthic"
            }
        }
    },

    autenthic: function(){
        console.log("Wazzup!?");
    }
});
```

I have my view:

```
Ext.define('myMoney.view.Inicio', {
    extend: 'Ext.form.Panel',
    xtype: 'inicio',

    requires: [
    'Ext.form.FieldSet',
    'Ext.field.Password'
    ],

    config: {
        title: 'Inicio',
        iconCls: 'home',
        styleHtmlContent: true,
        scrollable: true,

        items: [
            {
                xtype: 'toolbar',
                title: 'Money Tracker',
                docked: 'top'
            },
            {
                xtype: 'fieldset',
                title: 'Inicio de Sesion',
                id: 'loginForm',
                instructions: '(Por favor coloca tu usuario y clave)',

                items: [
                    {
                        xtype: 'textfield',
                        name: 'us',
                        label: 'Usuario'
                    },
                    {
                        xtype: 'passwordfield',
                        name: 'pw',
                        label: 'Clave'
                    }
                ]
            },
            {
                xtype: 'button',
                width: '50%',
                centered: true,
                text: 'Aceptar',
                ui: 'confirm',
                id: 'logButton'

            }
        ]

    }

});
```

What is wrong?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Instead of

```
tab: "autenthic"
```

write

```
tap: "autenthic"
```

Comment: I can believe that :/ well many hours on my PC last nigth and this is what i got. Thanks and i srry for that.