# Sencha Touch 2: tap on container doesn't work (tap on button works fine)

Tags: events, sencha-touch, sencha-touch-2, containers, tap

I have read the [SO question: Controller for Buttons Sencha Touch 2 [Solved]](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/11131813/controller-for-buttons-sencha-touch-2-solved) to achieve tapping the button. It works!

Unfortunately, I need tapping on the container, not the button. Once I change `xtype:'container'`, to `xtype:'button'`, it taps fine and I see the `console.log` message so everything works fine. Once I change it back to `xtype:'container'`, it stops working, there is no `console.log` message.

So, my question is: how to make tap event working for my `xtype:'container'`? Why does it work for buttons only? Am I missing something?

P.S. As far as I see there is no tap event for container. What's the solution then? Would making a button to have several strings of a text and a background be a solution?

OK, based on your answers, it is still unclear, how to make the button look like the container. The container is an image with two strings above. Here is my container:

```
{
    xtype:'container',
    cls:'home-img',
    id: 'home-img',
    layout : {
        type : 'vbox',
         align: 'middle'
    },
    items:[
          { xtype:'container',
            html:'Your current rate is:'  
          },
          { xtype:'container',
            tpl:'{rate}'
          }
          ],
},
```

Once I replace `xtype:'container'`, with `xtype:'button'`, I'm having difficulties to show {rate} parameter and unable to make two strings.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

In Sencha, there is no `tap` event available for a container. A container basically works like something which can hold different inner components/elements. However, you can indeed workaround if you want a tap event to be placed on container. As you have mentioned, you can go ahead and create a button, set a background, and set some strings (But that's not what a button should be used for, though). Or you can just set HTML with the desired string and background, make it a div and set Onclick event on it.

Answer (score 24):

I'm not a pro at sencha touch, but in this case i think you need a listener on the element.
this is what works for me:

```
Ext.define('RSSFramework.view.ListContainer', {
extend: 'Ext.Container',

config: {
    layout: {
        type: 'fit'
    },
    listeners:[
                 {
                    element: 'element',
                    event: 'tap',
                    fn: function() {
                        console.log('TAP!');
                    }
                }
            ]
}

});
```

Comment: best solution. does exactly what OP asks for

Comment: This is a better solution than the chosen one.

Comment: Thank you so much for your piece of code. Its really helped me

Comment: "Note: It is bad practice to specify a listener's config when you are defining a class using Ext.define(). Instead, only specify listeners when you are instantiating your class with Ext.create()."  http://docs-origin.sencha.com/touch/2.4/2.4.1-apidocs/#!/api/Ext.Container-cfg-listeners tho yes it works like a charm - wonder why is it bad practice doing it this way

Comment: also notice that if "element: 'element'," and you have a Component inside the Container tapping on the Component won't trigger the function and instead the config  needs to be element: 'innerElement',